# Spark schema management at single place

Tags: apache-spark, hive, databricks, aws-glue

### Question

*What is the best way to manage Spark tables' schemas? Do you see any drawbacks of Option 2? May you suggest any better alternatives?*

### Solutions I see

**Option 1: keep separate definitions for code and for metastore**

The drawback of this is approach is that you have continuously keep them in sync (error prone). Another drawback - it gets cumbersome if the table has 500 columns.

*create_some_table.sql [1st definition]*

```sql
-- Databricks syntax (internal metastore)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_table (
  Id int,
  Value string,
  ...
  Year int
)
USING PARQUET
PARTITION BY (Year)
OPTIONS (
  PATH 'abfss://...'
)
```

*some_job.py [2nd definition]*

```py
def run():
   df = spark.read.table('input_table')  # 500 columns
   df = transorm(df)
   # this logic should be in `transform`, but anycase it should be
   df = df.select(
     'Id', 'Year', F.col('Value').cast(StringType()).alias('Value')  # actually another schema definition: you have to enumerate all output columns
   )
   df.write.saveAsTable('some_table')
```

*test_some_job.py [3rd definition]*

```py
def test_some_job(spark):
   output_schema = ...  # another definition
   expected = spark.createDataFrame([...], output_schema)
```

**Option 2: keep only one definition in code (StructType)**

It's possible to generate schema on the fly. The benefit of this method - is simplicity and schema definition in single place. *Do you see any drawbacks?*

```py
def run(input: Table, output: Table):
   df = spark.read.table(input.name)
   df = transform(df)
   save(df, output)    

def save(df: DataFrame, table: Table): 
    df \
        .select(table.schema.fieldNames()) \
        .write \
        .partitionBy(table.partition_by) \
        .option('path', table.path) \
        .saveAsTable(table.name)
    # In case table doesn't exists, Databricks will automatically generate table definition
        
class Table(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    path: str
    partition_by: List[str]
    schema: StructType
```

Comment: In `some_job.py`, I see you are type casting your columns, `F.col('Value').cast(StringType()).alias('Value')`. Won't you have to do the same in Option 2 inside `save` function? If that is the case, I think it's better you make this generic as well. And have you thought about how you are going to generate schema on the fly? It will be better to keep a config file where you can store schema definition for all your tables and create Table objects using the schema file on application startup.

Comment: @wypul about schema generation - yes, I have to keep StructType for every table in my code. That benefit is that from StructType I can always generate SQL/Catalog definition, while from SQL/Catalog definition I can't generate StructType.

Comment: @wypul about casting I can create a generic method for all tables, like: `def select_cols_and_cast(df: DataFrame, schema: StructType) -> DataFrame:`

Comment: Well, if you already have a table you can create StructType from it by reading from the table and using `df.schema`. But anyway, better to not go down that path. Following Option 2 which is much cleaner approach, there are 3 points that I can think of to make it better: ( 1.) Implement generic method to transform dataframe in expected format(as you have done). ( 2.)   Instead of hard coding StructType for every table create it from a config file(This can be shared across multiple modules as a standard). ( 3.) Consider adding `bucketBy` option as well if you have high cardinality data.

Comment: @wypul sure, StructTypes are created from configs. About `bucketBy` I heard that it creates more issues then benefits. I heard that from Databricks support...

Answer (score 5):

Let me first make a few points then a recommendation.

1. Data lives a lot longer than code.
2. Code described above is code that creates & writes the data, there is also code that reads and consumes the data that needs to be considered.
3. There's a 3rd option, storing the definition of the data (schema) with the data. Often called a 'self describing format'
4. The structure of data can change over time.
5. This question is tagged with `databricks` and `aws-glue`
6. Parquet is self describing on a file by file basis.
7. Delta Lake tables use parquet data files, but additionally embed the schema into the transaction log and is thus the entire table and schema is versioned.
8. Data needs to be used by a wide eco system of tools, thus the data needs to be discoverable, the schema should not be locked into one compute engine.

Recommendation:

1. Store the schema with the data in an open format
2. Use Delta Lake format (which combines Parquet and a transaction log)
3. Change `USING PARQUET` to `USING DELTA`
4. Point your meta store to AWS Glue Catalog, Glue catalog will store the table name, and location
5. Consumers will resolve the schema from the Delta Lake table transaction log
6. Schema can evolve as the writer code evolves.

Results:

1. Your writer creates the schema, and may *optionally* evolve the schema
2. All consumers will find the schema (paired with the table version) in the Delta Lake (_delta_log dir to be specific)

Comment: first of all, thanks for your answer! I agree with your suggestions, but the point was that open format, Delta Lake or external metastore don't solve the issue of schema duplication. That happens because your code still requires schema in order to do selects, casts, controlled schema evolution, etc. So there are three options: 1) generate Metastore schema from code 2) read Metatore schema in code 3) duplicate schema at code and at Metastore. My assumption was that option #1 is much better then #2 and #3.

Comment: Updated with a 'results' to hopefully clarify.
Personally, because of my database design background, I always liked designing and putting the data model into the meta store.
Delta Lake changes things, in that you have an operational table for analytics with a time varying schema. A meta store isn't designed to track the fluid changes.

Thank you for the vote!

Answer (score 0):

At my company we have a very small team so we built a C# template based generator that reads information from a SQL Server database and generates all of our notebooks.  All information that is needed for generating the DDL schema and processing code for our entire system is in that database.  The only thing we code manually now is a portion of the load procedures for our Dims and Facts.  All of the boiler plate code is abstracted away. For new tables we go into our meta database enter the new table and column information and run the generator.  This results in the duplication that you are talking about in the resulting code but now we are just maintaining the metadatabase information instead of having to find all of the places that need to be updated.  If you already have a system built this method will be very hard to adapt also convincing upper management can be a challenge as there is a lot more development upfront.  However if you start from scratch with the mantra automate automate automate and work process by process on how you can make it generic you will gain an unparalleled ability to fix issues and stabilize your platform. The only product that I have seen in the wild that is capable of doing something similar in the big data space is Wherescape which is very expensive $35,000 per seat per year if I remember correctly. So if you have deep pockets I would highly suggest taking a look.  [https://www.wherescape.com/][1]
There may be others but that is the only one I know of.

A Couple of examples of how this approach can be a benefit.

1. We have two developers myself and one other and we were able to completely switch 130 staging and 40 Dim and Facts from U-SQL Datalake Analytics to Databricks in 4 months. Switching out every generated process as we went.
2. Lets say we find a processing issue in loading our staging tables we update the process template regenerate the notebooks and redeploy.  Process is now updated for all 130 tables half of day to day job that may have taken weeks to fix and test otherwise.

Comment: yes, looks like you're using totally different (an strange as for me) approach. We are using ETL Spark jobs with all transformations written in Spark Data Frame API. So I still need schema inside my Python code

Comment: My point is that you can generate your code no mater the language.  You can just as easily generate the Python files compile them with a build pipeline and auto deploy the resulting libraries to Databricks.  The only difference is that we use Scala with the spark DataFrames API and notebooks.  Not that you have to go that way just an option. You asked for a way to centralize the definition of the schema and one way to do that would be to have a metadata store and generate/orchestrate the system from that database.

Comment: if by code generation you mean transformation logic generation as well. Maybe for some narrow use cases generating the code is an option,  but usually generating code will always be more complex and error prone then just writting the "static" code. That might overweight the benefits of any schema duplication

Comment: if by code generation you mean only generation of StructType objects from Metastore - then yes, it's a vice versa approach to generation of Metastore schema from StructTypes. IMHO, Metastore -> StructType generation is worse because of two reasons: 1) Metastore doesn't support versioning. In case of schema evolution its logical that the first should be changed Spark code (integrated with Git), then the MEtastore should be auto-updated 2) I haven't found clean way to read JSON schemas from Metastore, at least as clean as generate it from StructType